Python Django OSError: [Errno 99] Address not available
I am creating an app with Django Rest Framework and struggling with a weird problem which occures when sending email with Djoser. When I try to reproduce this error on my host machine inside Docker container in production environment I do not have any errors, all email messages are sent succesfully, however when I try to do it on production server under Docker I get OsError, here is the full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 81, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 140, in perform_create
    settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/templated_mail/mail.py", line 78, in send
    super(BaseEmailMessage, self).send(*args, **kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 127, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 85, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(
                      
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 852, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 837, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: OSError at /api/auth/users/
Exception Value: [Errno 99] Address not available
Raised during: djoser.views.UserViewSet
Request information:

Here is my docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  # PostgreSQL
  db:
    image: postgres:12.18-alpine
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend-network
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

  # BackEnd
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod
    networks:
      - backend-network
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/backend
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:

Settings for SMTP server:
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = env("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = env("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")

I am sure that there are no problems with SMTP server I use, as on my computer it works fine, emails are sent. Also when I try to ping the SMTP server from Docker container on production server, I get some bytes recieved from it. Also, I think this issue is not related to Djoser.
I can not solve the problem for several days and have no idea what is going wrong.
I would be very grateful for any help
